# changing the color palette in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created ggplot from my data (sample below):

I have created a violin plot of the `NKV` with the individual `NKV` data points plotted over it. I want to differentiate betweeen which `PID` my datapoints belong to. So far so good:

```
violin.murgang <- ggplot(nkv.murgang, aes(x = factor("Murgang"), nkv.murgang$NK)) +
  geom_violin(color = "black", fill = "darkorange") + 
  ggtitle("NKV Murgang - Einfamilienhaus") + 
  labs(x = "Prozess", y = "Nutzen / Konsten \n Verhälhniss") +
  stat_summary(geom = "text", fun.y = quantile, 
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..)),
               position=position_nudge(x=0.4), size=3) +
  theme (legend.position = "none") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text",  position=position_nudge(x=-0.4)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(col = PID ), width = 0.35) 
violin.murgang
```

The problem is that all the `NKV` data points are only visualized in different shade of blue. I would like to have different colours. I have tried adding this:

```
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Spectral")
```

which yields the error:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

How can i achieve having different colour for the `geom_jitter` part?

What causes the error?

Thanks!

Comment: I think brewer colours only work for discrete variables.  Have a look at `scale_colour_gradient` and `scale_colour_gradient2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `PID` have more levels than colors of 'Spectral' palette, you could try `scale_color_distiller`, which extends brewer colors to continuous scale, see the manual of `scale_color_distiller`:

```
# Use distiller variant with continous data
v <- ggplot(faithfuld) +
    geom_tile(aes(waiting, eruptions, fill = density))
v
v + scale_fill_distiller()
v + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

Therefore, we could try:

```
ggplot(nkv.murgang, aes(x = factor("Murgang"), nkv.murgang$NK)) +
    geom_violin(color = "black", fill = "darkorange") + 
    ggtitle("NKV Murgang - Einfamilienhaus") + 
    labs(x = "Prozess", y = "Nutzen / Konsten \n Verhälhniss") +
    stat_summary(geom = "text", fun.y = quantile, 
                 aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..)),
                 position=position_nudge(x=0.4), size=3) +
    theme (legend.position = "none") + 
    geom_jitter(aes(color = PID), width = 0.35) +
    scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

If you data has a few levels, we could use discrete scales. `PID` is integer, which does work with discrete scales. You should convert it to character or factor first:

```
ggplot(nkv.murgang, aes(x = factor("Murgang"), nkv.murgang$NK)) +
    geom_violin(color = "black", fill = "darkorange") + 
    ggtitle("NKV Murgang - Einfamilienhaus") + 
    labs(x = "Prozess", y = "Nutzen / Konsten \n Verhälhniss") +
    stat_summary(geom = "text", fun.y = quantile, 
                 aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..)),
                 position=position_nudge(x=0.4), size=3) +
    theme (legend.position = "none") + 
    geom_jitter(aes(color = as.factor(PID) ), width = 0.35) +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Spectral")
```

Comment: Thanks @mt1022. Converting `PID` is what i was missing. Now `scale_color_brewer(palette = "Spectral")` works like a charm!